# The C Programming Language Exercise 3-3

Tags: c

Write a function expand(s1,s2) that expands shorthand notations like a-z in the string s1 into the equivalent complete list abc...xyz in s2. Allow for letters of either case and digits, and be prepared to handle cases like a-b-c and a-z0-9 and -a-z. Arrange that a leading or trailing is taken literally.

**Char array s1 changes after the assignment "s2[j++] = tmp" in expand(), but it is not supposed to change at all. Please kindly advise... Thanks**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void expand(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main () {
    char s1[] = {'a', '-', 'z'};
    char s2[26];
    expand(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
}

/*
    valid char : letters | number
    go through s1
    1. if valid char
        s1[i] = s2[j]
    2. if '-'
        2.1 (current_index - 1) & (current_index + 1) are valid indexes
            assign the valid char between s1[current_index - 1] and s1[current_index + 1] to s2
        2.2 (current_index - 1) | (current_index + 1) is not valid index
            s1[i] = s2[j]
*/

void expand (char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (;i < strlen(s1); i++) {
        char tmp = s1[i];
        if (('a' <= tmp && tmp <= 'z') || ('A' <= tmp && tmp <= 'Z') || ('0' <= tmp && tmp <= '9')) {
            s2[j++] = tmp;
        } else {
            if ((i - 1) >= 0 && (i+1) < strlen(s1)) {
                char start = s1[i-1];
                char end = s1[i+1];
                char c = start;
                while ((c = (c + 1)) < end)
                    s2[j++] = c;
            } else {
                s2[j++] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `s1` changes?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Run with Xcode under debug mode. I found s1 changes.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about `j`? Is it always between 0 and 25?

Comment: note that `for (;i < strlen(s1); i++)` is inefficient as it calculates `strlen` for every loop iteration, you should pre-calculate it before the loop

Comment: You are calculating strlen on s1, while s1 hasn't got a null-terminator ('\0')? That's suspicious right there... How would it be able to calculate it's length then? I think it should be ````char s1[] = {'a', '-', 'z', '\0'}```` to make strlen work.

Comment: @mkrieger1 j exceeds 25 due to s1 changes and strlen(s1) changes.

Comment: @AlanBirtles u r right. thanks

Comment: @BlayerBond but '\0' is not used as a terminator here...

Comment: the program works when putting pre-calculate before the loop `for (;i < strlen(s1); i++) `. but i still cannot figure out why s1 changes after each assignment.

Comment: `strlen` needs a properly terminated string, otherwise the behaviour is undefined. The same is true for `printf`. Use `char s1[] = "a-z";`

Comment: @molbdnilo u r right. the program runs correctly after revision. Thanks

Comment: @BlayerBond thank you. just got your suggestion

Comment: @AndyXu No problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

add the terminator `\0` to your string.

`char s1[] = {'a', '-', 'z','\0'};`